# Subversion over HTTP - can read but not write

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, svn

I'm trying to set up a Subversion server. It's on Fedora with SELinux enabled. I created a repository, and configured mod_dav_svn in Apache for remote access. `svn ls` works as expected - I get prompted for a password, and I see that there are no files in the repo. But when I try to `svn import`, I get an error. From the Apache error_log:

```
[Wed Jan 30 18:03:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] could not begin a transaction  [500, #13]
[Wed Jan 30 18:03:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Can't open file '/var/svn/testing/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied  [500, #13]
```

Apache should be able to read and write this file, so I have no idea what's wrong:

```
$ ls -Z /var/svn/testing/db/txn-current-lock
-rw-rw-r--. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/svn/testing/db/txn-current-lock
```

Comment: You did mention SELinux being enabled - did you check auditd's logs?

Comment: Thanks. I checked the logs, and it does look like SELinux is the culprit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, as this was answered in a comment.

Check `auditd`'s log, almost certainly in these situations `SELinux` is to blame, you mentioned it's enabled.

Comment: You're right, it was SELinux. This fixed it: `setsebool -P httpd_unified 1`